# Secure authentication to LUIS account

Tags: authentication, linguistics, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am going to use LUIS service in my application. How can I provide secure authentication to my account? I want to make sure that nobody uses my subscription key to make own calls. I have LUIS app id and LUIS subscription key. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure that the Microsoft account you use to sign in to LUIS is secure (I recommend enabling 2 factor authentication enabled).
Second, make sure that nobody sees the URL you are using (like in a demo session, or hard coding it in your code)

Comment: Thank you Mokhtar. But what do you mean by "enabling 2 factor authentication enabled"?

Comment: @irahis in your Microsoft account (ex: Hotmail) security settings you can enable the option to get a code on mobile through sms or authentication app to make the sign in process more secure

Comment: Ok, I understand! Thank you!